# Is there a way to share OTR keys between different applications?

Tags: encryption, instant-messaging

I have IM+ pro installed on my phone and purchased the OTR upgrade.
On my linux laptop I have pidgin installed and the OTR plugin active.

I set both XMPP resources - laptop and nexus - to the same priority, I simply set IM+ pro to 1, to share messages between devices. I prefer to use OTR communication whenever possible but I have not yet found a way to share the OTR keys already on my laptop with my phone.

How can I achieve OTR communication that can be decrypted on both devices equally?